# $\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2cos^{2n}xdx \leq \frac{C}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}cos^{2n}xdx$

Tags: calculus

I was working on an exercise in calculus, and I somehow failed to prove the following:

$$B_n:=\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2cos^{2n}xdx \leq \frac{C}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}cos^{2n}xdx=:\frac{C}{n}A_n $$ for some constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$

By using integration by parts, we can obtain

$$2nB_{n-1}-2nB_n = \frac{1}{n}A_n$$

Is there any further hint?

Answer (score 1):

Basing on your formula we have
$$B_{n-1}-B_n={1\over 2n^2}A_n$$ Therefore
$$B_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (B_{k-1}-B_k)=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty {1\over 2k^2}A_k\\ \le A_{n+1}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty {1\over 2k^2}
\le {1\over 2n}A_n$$